# How to clear/reset the results in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am running a stored procedure that should generate the `scope_id`, but is returning a number of sets of results.

This code:

```
  INSERT INTO ..
  SELECT @AddedID = SCOPE_INDENTITY()
  EXEC NewSP --Returns a Scope_Identity also
```

How do I accomplish this (clearing the results and starting fresh):

```
  INSERT INTO..
  SELECT @AddedID = SCOPE_INDENTITY()
  EXEC NewSP --Returns a Scope_Identity also

  CLEAR_ALL_RESULTS -- Need to be able to clear all the results here

  SELECT @AddedID as AddedID  --Only return this results now after clearing all prior
```

Comment: Cant' your work with an output parameter?

Comment: When i run the sp in an app, it returns the select scope_id from the "NewSP" instead of the @AddedID, i don't know how to target this sp to return the AddedID instead of the NewSP Scope_id

Comment: @ZeeTee - The whole benefit of using `SCOPE_IDENTITY` rather than `@@IDENTITY` is that it doesn't get altered by child scopes so not sure what you mean? Are you saying that the stored proc returns a result set that you want to discard? If so can you alter that stored procedure definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using "output" is good idea :) ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx))

```
create table #ttable
(
    id int primary key identity,
    someText nvarchar(20)
)
Go
Insert Into #ttable (someText) 
Output inserted.id
Values ('Some text');
```

Answer (score 0):

you could always use an [output parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: [Don't answer with just a link.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)